# Reduce chat feed bot delay for new questions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, chat

Our feed bots post questions with delays of up to 20 minutes. Could we make them post as soon as questions appear on the main page or in Questions tab?

Comment: One technical issue with this proposal: it's possible (in fact not difficult) to create a feed that will snowball out of control, or just flood the room with a huge number of posts, even if we restrict to SE-internal feeds. The feed users are not rate-limited, so the refresh rate is the only thing that would stop a room from being absolutely swamped. While 20 minutes is rather long to wait, I don't think it should be reduced below 1-2 minutes for that reason.

Comment: I don't think developers are so silly that they would let something like this happen. Worst case scenario they could fix it in a matter of minutes for a very long time.

Answer (score 3):

Feeds have a use for bringing external data into the chat in an asynchronous manner, but feeds are all (by definition) poll-based, and all carry overhead. We don't poll aggressively, in part to avoid impact on us, and in part to be good web citizens and not hammer external sites.

Now, for internal feeds like "all newest questions", "all new [sometag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sometag) questions", etc, we *could* theoretically change a few things and talk directly to ourselves (perhaps even avoiding the *actual feed*, and going direct to the source via a private API, possibly even the real-time API that drives the question list updates) - but it seems to be a dubious benefit, and if you *really want* the "questions tab" functionality: *open the questions tab*, and it is already there. Chat is not meant to replace every other UI/API, and it does not seem a good option to drag every question into chat "just because".

But:

- there's a lot of work here
- the "benefit" seems minimal, and possibly even harmful

So; in the **current state**, I don't think we'd do this. If there was a scenario with a really great explanation as to why it is a good idea, then: maybe.